# How to fix No component factory found for NgxMaterialTimepickerContainerComponent error?

Tags: datepicker, angular8

I'm using ngx-material-timepicker in my project.when I use the latest 5.2.2, I'm getting the following error

```
ng:///NgxMaterialTimepickerModule/NgxMaterialTimepickerToggleComponent.n 
gfactory.js:13 ERROR Error: No component factory found for NgxMaterialTimepickerContainerComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (:4401/vendor.js:87649)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (:4401/vendor.js:87714)
    at DomService.appendTimepickerToBody (:4401/main-exams-exams-module.js:8424)
    at NgxMaterialTimepickerComponent.open (:4401/main-exams-exams-module.js:8848)
    at NgxMaterialTimepickerToggleComponent.open (:4401/main-exams-exams-module.js:8994)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///NgxMaterialTimepickerModule/NgxMaterialTimepickerToggleComponent.ngfactory.js:19)
    at handleEvent (:4401/vendor.js:103240)
    at callWithDebugContext (:4401/vendor.js:104859)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (:4401/vendor.js:104494)
    at dispatchEvent (:4401/vendor.js:90327)
```

But when I downgraded to version 4.0.0 it worked perfectly.

// module page

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxMaterialTimepickerModule } from 'ngx-material-timepicker';
@NgModule({
declarations: [appComponent ],
  imports: [NgxMaterialTimepickerModule]
]
})
```

html

```
<div>
    <ngx-material-timepicker-toggle [for]="defaultValue"></ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
    <ngx-material-timepicker #defaultValue></ngx-material-timepicker>
    <input aria-label="default time" [ngxTimepicker]="defaultValue" [value]="'05:11 pm'" required readonly>
</div>
```

Can someone help me with the latest version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the same error and was able to fix it. Since you are using lazy load of angular you need to import `NgxMaterialTimepickerModule` in your app.module as well.